# Elasticsearch terms aggrecation result count

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

I need to query the number of returning customers from a webshop's database for a given month.

I tied the following query(customers who have more than 1 order):

```
GET webshop/orders/_search
{
  "size": 0, 
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "created_at": {
              "gte": "2017-01-01",
              "lte": "2017-01-31"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "orders_count": {
      "terms": {
        "size": 0, 
        "field": "user_email",
        "min_doc_count": 2
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The result is something like this:

```
{
  "took": 22,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 12,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "orders_count": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "email@gmail.com",
          "doc_count": 12
        },...
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

How should I change the query to get the count of the buckets returned?

Comment: As far as I know you can only count the number of buckets on the client side, no field is returned with that information.

Comment: @Val would using [Cardinality](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-cardinality-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-metrics-cardinality-aggregation) do the needful?

Comment: Yes, it might, feel free to try.

Comment: Thanks you for the tips!

Comment: @Val Another thing, is there a way to filter the buckets array by doc_count using Elasticsearch?

Comment: What do you mean by "filter"? Do you want only buckets with at least X docs to appear?

Comment: @Val For example I want only those where doc_count = 1

Comment: Someone once asked for adding a `max_doc_count` setting, but that was not deemed important at that point. Even though there is a workaround, you can revive that thread if you want: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/19565

Comment: @Val okey, thanks again!